# htaccess remove one specific folder name, leave the others intact

Tags: .htaccess

I need to rewrite

> http://www.example.com/landrover/content/home.php

to

> http://www.example.com/landrover/home.php

I've tried entering the following into the .htaccess within the landrover folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But all it does is rewrite it to http://www.example.com/home.php

All I want to do is remove the /content/ part from the url and leave everything else. I honestly can't find the solution to this simple problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in `landrover/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /landrover/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /content/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=308,NC,NE]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache.